# how do I access a header file from a different DKM in Wind River Workbench?

Tags: eclipse, vxworks, workbench

I want to access a header file that's "far away" from my local files (DKM) and am wondering how I can generate a respective link from within Workbench?
The file I need to include is located at: `../../../../somedir/otherDKM/src/somedir/header.h` - if I just include this file with that path in my file, it won't compile because there's an include from within the header.h file and that path then won't be found once it's included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have imported the "otherDKM" project into the workspace, you can add that project directory to your include paths, eg something like:

`-I%otherDKMProjName%/src/somedir/`

and then in your code just include the header:

`#include "header.h"`

Assuming `header.h` includes things already in the include paths, or local to itself, then that should work for you